# Using HATEOAS and Backbone.js

Tags: rest, backbone.js, hateoas

I've started experimenting with Backbone.js, and was struck by the documentation for the documentation for the [url](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url) property on Backbone.Model.

In particular, I'm building out a REST API that uses HATEOAS/hypermedia to drive the client(s).

I can see the usefulness of Backbone's default behaviour of building up URLs itself for items in a collection, but for my case, would prefer to have the model URLs built out of the data that is parsed.

Has anyone extended/built on Backbone to make it do this? Maybe building upon a "standard" like [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)?

**EDIT:**

For clarification, let's say I have the following:

GET /orders >>

```
[
  {
     "_links": {
       "self": "/orders/123"
     }
     "name": "Order #123",
     "date": "2012/02/23"
  },
  {
     "_links": {
       "self": "/orders/6666"
     }
     "name": "Order #666",
     "date": "2012/03/01"
  },
]
```

and I have an Order model like:

```
var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
```

I would like the `url` property to be automatically pulled out of the "self" reference in the HAL. I think creating a new base model something like (not tested):

```
var HalModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return get("_links").self;
  },
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you saying that if you have an order model that you want the Url to be set dynamically to 'order/{orderid}' and if you have a customer model, the same code would set it to 'customer/{customerid}' ?

Comment: @timDunham See my edit for more clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification @Pete.

I think I see what your proposing and I suppose it could work.  However, in your example, you first had to know the `/Orders` url before you were able to get the orders.  And if you reworked your json to have an `id` property, you'd be pretty close to the default implementation of backbone.

Now if you just want to use a generic model or base model (e.g. `HALModel`) and just bootstrap it with data, your approach could be useful and definitely could work.  However, I would look at overriding [parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) to pull the url out and set it on the model:

```
parse: function(response) {
    this.url = response._links.self;
    delete response._links;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Yes, knowing the /orders URL comes from a GET to the base URL for the service, which using a HATEOAS approach would return the links for all the available resources:GET / >> { "_links": { "urn:mysite.com:orders": "/orders" }

Comment: I like the use of the parse function. Do I need to chain up to the base parse method with Backbone.Model.prototype.parse.call(this, response); ?

Comment: It's not necessary to chain up.  By default `parse` return `response`.

Comment: @Pete how would this then be called when instantiating a model? Could you provide a full example? ie: the entire model declaration and implementation? Thanks

Comment: @TomGillard At this point, i would recommend using Mike Kelly's backbone.hal library.

Answer (score 10):

I've extended backbone to do exactly this, the library is available here:

https://github.com/mikekelly/backbone.hal

Answer (score 2):

I complement here the response of Simon to explain how to easily do it using [gomoob/backbone.hateoas](https://github.com/gomoob/backbone.hateoas).

```
// Instanciation of an Hal.Model object is done the same way as you're 
// used to with a standard Backbone model
var user = new Hal.Model({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    _links: {
        avatar: {
            href: "http://localhost/api/users/1/avatar.png" 
        },
        self: {
            href: "http://localhost/api/users/1"
        }
    },
    _embedded: {
        address: {
            "city" : "Paris",
            "country" : "France",
            "street" : "142 Rue de Rivoli",
            "zip" : "75001",
            "_links" : {
                "self" : {
                    "href" : "http://localhost/api/addresses/1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

// Now we you can easily get links, those lines are equivalent
var link1 = user.getLink('avatar');
var link2 = user.getLinks().get('avatar'); 

// So getting self link is simple too
var self = user.getLink('self');

// All the Hal.Link objects returned by backbone.hateoas are in fact 
// standard Backbone models so its standard Backbone
link1.get('href');
link1.getHref();

// You can do more with shortcut methods if your HAL links 
// have more properties
link1.get('deprecation');
link1.getDeprecation();
link1.get('name');
link1.getName();
link1.get('hreflang');
link1.getHreflang();
link1.get('profile');
link1.getProfile();
link1.get('title');
link1.getTitle();
link1.get('type');
link1.getType();
linke1.get('templated');
link1.isTemplated();

// You can also manipulate embedded resources if you need
user.getEmbedded('address').get('city');
user.getEmbedded('address').getLink('self');
...
```

Finally we provide an Hal.Model.url() implementation which is more powerful than standard Backbone url() and which is very useful if you use HAL.

```
// By default url() returns the href of the self link if this self 
// link is present
user.url(); 

// If the self link is not defined then url() has the same behavior 
// as standard Backbone url() method
// My user is link to a user collection having a URL equal to 
// 'http://localhost/user1'
user.url(); // http://localhost/users/1

// My user is not link to a user collection in this case the URL is 
// generate using the model urlRoot property by default
user.urlRoot = 'http://myserver/users';
user.url(); // http://localhost/users/1

// backbone.hateoas also allows you to define an application wide root 
// URL which prevent to use absolute URLs everywhere in your code
Hal.urlRoot = 'http://localhost/api';  // HAL root API URL

var user = new Hal.Model({ id : 1});
user.urlMiddle = 'users'; 
user.url(); // http://localhost/api/users/1
```

Hope this helps, don't hesitate to post issues on our github if you need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the url function on the model to calculate the URL however you want; it's completely extensible.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen I can override it manually for a particular model. I'm curious if anyone has a more generic/reusable approach they've taken.